# Imgur application registration link invalid?

Tags: imgur

I am trying to register my application on Imgur in order to obtain the  client_id and client_secret as according to the documentation, but the link provided in the docs only redirects me to my Imgur account home page.  Has the registration link been changed?

https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient

Answer (score 0):

Now it should be working. I registered two apps today.